# PHP making blank file when I try to increment my variable?

Tags: php, file, increment, race-condition

I recently made a PHP program to count how many users are online using a program I created. It works like this:

1. Client sends register request to server (registerMember.php)
2. Server checks if the user is already online
3. If the user isn't already online, increment a number in a file
4. Write the persons username to a text file

My problem is that a lot of people would register in at the same time, and that would create a blank file.

```
    $file_handle = fopen("registeredMembers", "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
        $line = fgets($file_handle);
        $line++;
        $fp = fopen('registeredMembers', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $line);
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

This is happening because there are two requests happening at the same time, and before the program writes the incremented version of the variable, another request has read a blank file before writing. Is there a better way I could be doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Great job in expressing your first question.

Answer (score 3):

Try blocking the file with [flock](https://www.php.net/flock) after you open it (see the example inside).